# Key repeat command in 16.04

Tags: command-line, keyboard, 16.04

14.04 commnad:

```
"dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/keyboard/repeat true"
```

doesn't work in 16.04.

Unfortuantely in game that I play command

```
xset r off
```

also doesn't work.

Is there a command line to disable keyrepeat as it is annoying to have to go to settings menu everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set this key to `false`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat false
```

The same via `dconf`:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/keyboard/repeat false
```